# How do I adjust the pitch range of the Midi pitch bend control?

Tags: midi, ableton-live

I would like to pitch bend my midi data, while in session view, clip view and Envelopes tab, as is shown in the picture. I have selected midi ctrl in device chooser. Then I selected pitch bend in the control chooser.

How do I adjust the range of the maximal pitch bending ? I would like it to be octave (12 st).

ps. I using a the simpler instrument to convert a sample to midi data here. When I use a midi instrument from the core library I can also only amount of midi semi tones.

With the Sampler Instrument I CAN adjust the pitch bend range ! Should I use Sampler the whole time or have I missed a button in Simpler or with ordinary midi instruments

[image: Dive: midi ctrl, control: pitch bend]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A MIDI pitch-bend controller sends values in the range -8192 to 8191. The interpretation of those data values to an actual pitch change is done by the hardware or the software plug-in receiving the MIDI signal. You will either need to adjust the sensitivity there or change the sensitivity via MIDI [RPNs](http://www.philrees.co.uk/nrpnq.htm) (registered parameter numbers). Some devices allow for setting the pitch bend range with SysEx commands.

Comment: I'll will happily accept your answer if you explain how to adjust the sensitivity in the simple case of a generic midi software instrument. What button is that ?

Comment: I already know how to do it in Sampler. I'm just interested in the button for a generic midi instrument

Comment: This answer is just wrong, even though accepted. PitchBend sensitivity is an RPN command set. Ought to be recognised by most devices these days. BTW, for some odd reason that sequencer seems to combine the MSB & LSB PB values as though they were one. I suppose it would work, it just feels a bit odd, especially when few synths even acknowledge the LSB exists ;)

Comment: This isn't answer isn't really wrong, just lacking some details. "You will need to adjust the sensitivity there" ... you may be able to adjust it in the device/plugin's user interface somewhere, or by sending an RPN or NRPN or SysX message. I'm pretty sure there's at least one MIDI device out there that doesn't allow changing the pitch bend range at all. You might also be able to use VST/AU/etc _automation_ to do the change.

Comment: As an aside, that website is really nostalgic, I bet it's the kind that Google doesn't index anymore nowadays...

Comment: @htmlcoderexe MIDI hasn't changed much in the last twenty years, but please feel free to suggest a better reference.

Comment: @PiedPiper I am sorry - this may have come over as negative. I meant it in the best way possible, I enjoyed reading the website and I love the aesthetics, I was simply lamenting the fact that these websites are much harder to come by in 2022.

Answer (score 5):

Pitch bend sensitivity can be controlled by RPN [Registered Parameter Number] messages.
To save reams of complicated detail, an RPN is two bytes followed by a controller value of one or two bytes
(just take it as read;)

```
CC 100 value 0 RPN MSB
CC 101 value 0 RPN LSB
CC   6 value [PB amount]  MSB
CC  38 value [PB fine-tune] LSB [optional]
```

Some trial & error may be needed to see what CC6 value corresponds to what sensitivity in the particular device. I vaguely recall it's in semitones, but it's been too long & the official Midi documentation is for mathematicians, which I am not.

To be tidy, once you've sent this set of messages, you should close it down to prevent misinterpretations by sending

```
    CC 100 value 127 
    CC 101 value 127
```

Comment: Cool answer! I got synths that had different pitchbend range per oscillators, hence needed to be configured in the synths... I guess this wouldn't work with RPN...

Comment: They may have an NRPN or even SysEx - you'd have to look it up in the manual. NRPNs work in the same way -Open 98/value 99/value CC6, CC32, close again with 127s.

Comment: Do you volunteer to answer the logical follow-up question, "how do I actually do this in Ableton Live?" :D Out of curiosity, I tried to construct an RPN message block in Ableton, using MIDI automation curves drawn on a MIDI clip, but I couldn't get it to do anything. Plugins tried: RealGuitar 2, NI FM8, Ableton Simpler, Ableton Sampler. Maybe it's possible to send an RPN with Max4Live. By the way, RPN LSB CC# should be 38, not 32. 32 is Bank Select LSB. Ableton calls CCs 6+38 "Data Entry".

Comment: I don't use Ableton, sorry, so I've no clue how to configure this. If it has a plain ol' Grid Edit midi editor, then it's just a case of clicking in new CC events, & changing them to the correct CC numbers & values. Ooops, yes, typo, 38. Fixed.